# WFP Binding List oc Object to a Custume Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, bind

I am trying to bind a device object List to a costume control i am working on. I getting this error.

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Devices' property of type
>   'CamaraSelection'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty
>   of a DependencyObject.

xml code

```
<trainControl:CamaraSelection  Devices="{Binding DeviceList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Control Code

```
    private List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeviceListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DeviceList", typeof(List<Device>), typeof(CamaraSelection),
                            new PropertyMetadata(default(ItemCollection), OnDeviceListChanged));


    private static void OnDeviceListChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var camaraSelection = dependencyObject as CamaraSelection;

        if (camaraSelection != null)
        {
            camaraSelection.OnDeviceListChanged(dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs);
        }
    }
    private void OnDeviceListChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public List<Device> Devices
    {
        get { return (List<Device>)GetValue(DeviceListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeviceListProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property where the binding is set on has to be a `DependencyProperty`. In your case it's the `Devices`-property. The first argument in the DependencyProperty.Register() method has to be the name of your property. The first argument in your code is `"DeviceList"` but your Property's name is `Devices`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DevicesProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Devices", typeof(List<Device>), typeof(CamaraSelection),
                        new PropertyMetadata(default(ItemCollection), OnDeviceListChanged));


public List<Device> Devices
{
    get { return (List<Device>)GetValue(DevicesProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(DevicesProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"Devices" Property in your class must be a dependency property not the "DeviceList". The property which you are binding to must be a dependency property.